# regexp pattern substitution

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I want to replace everything in .* with “.*” in the following regex expression. Can someone please help?

```
/((This).*(has).*(features).*)/gm
```

So for example:
Original: `This red car has many features that don’t work`

Replacement: `This “red car” has “many” features “that don’t work”`

Comment: You should match and capture the unknown parts and then use backreferences to those group values. See `This\s+(.*\S)\s+has\s+(.*\S)\s+features\s*(.*)` => `This “$1” has “$2” features “$3”` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBCqWM/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is also removing/omitting the next line. How do I exclude that? [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBCqWM/2)

Comment: You are not testing against standalone strings, so replace `\s` with `\h` if you want to stay matching within a line, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBCqWM/3).